# Add a method to class when drag/drop a component to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a server component (C# ASP.NET 4.0) that relies on a method in page class.

I like to automatically add a method to page code behind when component dragged from visual studio toolbox and dropped to page.

Is it possible to do this?

**Edit:** What I'm trying to do is making programmers job easier by suggesting (adding) methods that they might need to operate my component. What I want to happen is like the time that programmer double click on a component in a page and a method is added to code behind and its reference is added to component in page but I want it to add right the time that component dropped into page.

Programmers might remove the method or use some other method or even not use it at all.

Comment: Bob, just wondering: the user could still remove the method. Wouldn't it be better to require the page to implement an specific interface?

Comment: @AndreCalil, What I'm trying to do is making programming job easier by suggesting (adding) methods that are needed by my component to page. Obviously programmers need to fill in the blanks (code inside method) to make it work and as you said they might not even want to use that method at all.

Comment: That's right, but if they remove the method the ASCX we still function properly or they might get some runtime exceptions?